# Libgdx - dispose method not triggered if the app is closed while on pause

Tags: android, libgdx

I am getting started with libgdx so my question might sound silly :D. I've noticed that the dispose method in the application listener is not triggered when the app is closed from the multitasking menu on android (while on pause).
I need to know how to overcome this problem because the lines of code I've written in the dispose method is only executed when I close the app from itself, not from the multitasking while on pause!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Android's `onDestroy()` method, `dispose()` is not guaranteed to be called. If you are doing anything like trying to save the game or the game state, you have to do it in `pause()`.

You don't need to worry about assets not being disposed as a result of `dispose` not getting called, because if this happens, your entire app's memory is being reclaimed by the system anyway. So just make sure anything that implements Disposable is disposed of in `dispose` to handle the case where a user backs out of your game (which closes the Android activity but does not completely close the application).

Comment: I know it's been a long time since this, but I'm seeing instances in which Android's onDestroy() is called but dispose() is not!